# Perform bash command after connecting to Ubuntu server (Windows 10)

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, automation

I'm trying to make a simple Windows batch script that will make my life easier, but i don't know if it's quite possible. It basically automatically connect to the Ubuntu server using SSH. But when i enter the server, none of my commands work (as you would expect, since is a different terminal). However, i made a shell script and placed in the root directory of the server (ubuntu@ip-182-74-3-112:~$) that performs the actions, i just need to execute this script automatically when i connect to the Ubuntu server. Is it possible?

Batch script:

```
cd "C:\Users\myUser\Documents"
ssh -i .\my_server.pem ubuntu@www.website.com.br

// ./restart.sh (doesn't work)
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "server/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/"

for i in 1 2 3; do

sudo ./asadmin stop-domain domain1

done

for i in 1 2; do

sudo ./asadmin start-domain domain1

done
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple that didn't come to my mind. I just changed

```
cd "C:\Users\myUser\Documents"
ssh -i .\my_server.pem ubuntu@www.website.com.br
```

to

```
cd "C:\Users\myUser\Documents"
ssh -i .\my_server.pem ubuntu@www.website.com.br "./restart.sh; bash"
```

Ignore my question, i'm just leaving here for convenience